# How we put customize Date Format in a label in form application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a label named `Label1`. I retrieve a date from database. And I want to put it in this label. Fine. Now By default its format came like this:: `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS (AM/PM)`. But I want it like `DD/MM/YYYY`.

How can I change this format?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Does your date come from the database as a DateTime or as just a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to format the date string;
Example

```cs
while (dr.Read()) 
{ 
  var date = dr["accountPeriodTo"];
  lblToDate.Text = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

URL for possible formats (from Code Project):

[Formats for DateTime.ToString()](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19677/Formats-for-DateTime-ToString)

Comment: :: I fatch this value from database.
 while (dr.Read())
               {
                   lblToDate.Text = dr["accountPeriodTo"].ToString();
}

Now how can I change lblToDate formt?

Comment: there is an error. "No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments"

Comment: @AnimeshGhosh The `var date = dr["accountPeriodTo"];` needs to be of type DateTime, what is it currently returning? You might need to convert it to a DateTime first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DateTime.ToString(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) overload.

> Converts the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent
>   string representation **using the specified format**.

Something like;

```
Label1.Text = YourDateValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Check out

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
var someVar = DateTime.Now;
Label1.Text = someVar.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Do you really think, you should write the same answer that has written already?

Comment: I opened this thread as soon as the question was posted. no one posted the answer at that time.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
label.text = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the database is spitting out the date as string, then probably the easiest would be:

```
Label1.Text = dateStringFromDB.Split(' ')[0];
```

though the following might be a little bit more robust:

```
Label1.Text = DateTime.Parse(dateStringFromDB).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Obviously both of these answers assume your original date is stored as a string named `dateStringFromDB`.